# ACPI_BIOS_ERROR with Windows 10 Installation Media

Tags: windows, bios, bsod, windows-installation, acpi

I have been experiencing some issues on Arch such as the WiFi part of `RTL8723BS` not working, and the power button not working. I have narrowed it down to the BIOS, so I am trying to flash it. Unfortunatly it seems that the only way to do that on this Lenovo MIIX 310-ICR would be to use the OEM tool available only on Windows.

Since I don't have Windows installed, I made an installation USB, but when I try to boot, I instantly get an `ACPI_BIOS_ERROR` BSOD, which I think is related to the issues I've been having on Arch.

Since I believe I need to flash the BIOS to fix it, I need to get Windows working, but it won't work until I flash the BIOS.

How can I break this cycle?

Edit<sub>1</sub>:
I see this in the systemd messages during Arch boot:

```
intel-spi intel-spi: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 25 35 c2 25 35
intel-spi intel-spi: failed to locate the chip
intel-spi intel-spi: failed to locate the chip
```

A quick search directed me to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250121), which suggests a corrupted Intel ME. Could this be the main cause?

Edit<sub>2</sub>: As per harrymc's request:
Following the methods listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux), I got the following:

**fuwpd:**

```
# fwupdmgr get-updates
No updatable devices
```

**Flashrom:** This tool is for desktop motherboards and generally should not be used for laptops. Furthermore, it requires a BIOS image, which I couldn't aquire since the OEM only provides an update tool for Windows, and I was not able to extract the .exe

**FreeDOS:** This machine just wouldn't see the FreeDOS live USB no matter what I did, so I couldn't use it.
It could be related to having to enable legacy boot, but there is nothing in the BIOS settings other than a secure boot toggle, and a BIOS back flash toggle which is used to allow downgrading the BIOS using once again, the provided Windows tool.

**Bootable optical disk emulation:** Once again, this requires a BIOS image that I don't have.

Edit<sub>3</sub>:
I forgot to mention that these issues started happening when I tried to install `systemd-boot`. I'm not sure whether it is related or it's purely coincidental.

**Edit<sub>4 & Final</sub>**: Since this question has suffered from an XY problem, I've rewritten it [here](https://superuser.com/q/1532903/862944).

Comment: How did you create the installation media?

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded the ISO from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO then used WoeUSB on Linux to burn it into a USB stick

Comment: Try something like - disable AHCI in BIOS settings, make clock speed normal aka. no overclocking, boot into UEFI mode etc.

Comment: You might want to visit these two sites (1) https://github.com/corna/me_cleaner/wiki/How-to-apply-me_cleaner  and # 2 which is a link from the #1. (2) https://hardenedlinux.github.io/firmware/2016/11/17/neutralize_ME_firmware_on_sandybridge_and_ivybridge.html

Comment: You can do it from Linux. See the Arch Linux article [Flashing BIOS from Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux) for several methods. If one of them works for you, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Biswapriyo literally the only thing this BIOS allows to set is secure boot.

Comment: @harrymc I've already checked that, and this machine apparently doesn't support any of these methods.

Comment: You have tried all of these methods and none worked? Surprising. Can you add to your post the problems you ran into with each of the methods?

Comment: @harrymc added.

Comment: I understand your problem is to extract the BIOS from the installer. Try to use [innoextract](https://constexpr.org/innoextract/) for that : `innoextract 1hcn44ww.exe`. See [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/flash-your-lenovo-ideapad-laptop-bios-from-linux-using-uefi-capsule-updates-a82e455ea29c).

Comment: @harrymc that was quite successful I think. I got a `bios.bin`, in addition to some `dll`s and `exe`s. Although I couldn't follow the entire tutorial since I didn't get a capsule.

Comment: `bios.bin` is all you need. Let me know if you succeed now and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Welp, the BIOS flash was successful, but it had no effect on the ACPI issues I'm trying to solve. I don't know what to do next really.

Comment: (I wonder now if I did answer the bounty question or not.) It did seem unlikely for me that the fault was in the BIOS, it's more likely in the driver. Please do: `sudo modprobe rtl8723bs` and then post the errors or warnings: `dmesg | grep rtl`. After this, check the wifi, sometimes this fixes it.

Comment: @harrymc There are things other than the Wi-Fi that suddenly stopped working like the power button and the lid switch. The Wi-Fi device doesn't show up at all in `lspci`, there is no wireless interface in `ip link`, `rfkill` only shows bluetooth, and for the buttons, `journalctl -f` shows no messages when those are triggered, while it does show messages for other buttons. Even Windows won't work and would BSOD on boot. Anyway, `dmesg | grep rtl` doesn't show any warnings, and `modprobe` didn't find a module named `rtl8723bs`.

Comment: You did mention "RTL8723BS" in the post. Did these ever work? Did you try to reinstall Linux?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that many devices have stopped working, not only the WiFi adapter,
it seems that you have had a catastrophic error, either software or hardware.

As you are currently using Arch Linux, as test you could try a Live USB of Arch Linux.

If this works, then your Arch Linux installation is corrupted. The best solution
would be to save your data and reinstall Arch Linux from scratch.

If the Live USB shows the same problems, then the problem is hardware, and perhaps
it would be better to consult a repairman.
Just to note that, as the Lenovo MIIX 310-ICR came out in 2016,
it is quite normal for a laptop not to last for more than five years.

Comment: Those issues appear even on a live USB of Ubuntu. I still think it could be a low-level software issue since these issues started when I tried to install `systemd-boot` (forgot to mention this, my bad), which might've triggered a bug somewhere. It could also be purely coincidental. In any case, I'll award the bounty to this if I don't get a better answer.

Comment: I understand now why you thought the BIOS was indicated. Reinstalling Arch Linux might help in that case, but it's far from sure.