# Multiple issues after trying to install systemd-boot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, firmware, acpi, hardware-detection

<sup>This question is a follow up of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1522106/862944) which suffered from an XY problem</sup>

I have a Lenovo MIIX 310-ICR with Arch installed on it. I tried to install `systemd-boot` to replace `rEFInd` since I wanted to get rid of Windows and no longer needed to see a graphical bootloader to choose an OS during boot. I followed the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) to install it, and after a reboot, several issues appeared:

- WiFi stopped working entirely. The `wlan0` interface doesn't show up under `ip link` nor `rfkill`. The WiFi/Bluetooth device is a `RTL8723BS`, and the bluetooth part of it still works.
- The power button and lid switch stopped working on Arch (power button works for turning on the device or hard resets). Unlike WiFi, those at least seem to be detected. From `dmesg`:

  ```
  [    1.794961] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
  [    1.795040] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
  [    1.795181] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
  [    1.795238] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
  [    1.795358] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
  [    1.797222] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
  ```

Things I've tried to do:

- Install Windows again to check if those issues appear there. I downloaded installation media from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), burned it onto a USB stick with WoeUSB, and when I booted it, It instantly BSOD'd and gave an `ACPI_BIOS_ERROR`.
- Flash the BIOS. I wasn't able to use Windows, so I followed [this](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/flash-your-lenovo-ideapad-laptop-bios-from-linux-using-uefi-capsule-updates-a82e455ea29c)
  to do it from Arch. Nothing changed after flashing.

Some lines from `dmesg` that I think are related:

```
[    0.990130] dw_dmac 80862286:00: Missing DT data
[    1.023446] dw_dmac 808622C0:00: Missing DT data
[    7.076454] intel-int3496 INT3496:00: can't get USB ID IRQ: -6
[    7.854389] gpio-keys gpio-keys.2.auto: Failed to request GPIO 349, error -16
[    7.857169] gpio-keys: probe of gpio-keys.2.auto failed with error -16
[    8.209353] intel-spi intel-spi: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 25 35 c2 25 35
[    8.209498] intel-spi intel-spi: failed to locate the chip
[    8.209521] intel-spi: probe of intel-spi failed with error -2
```

I am not sure if installing `systemd-boot` had anything to do with those issues, or it was purely coincidental.

**Edit<sub>1</sub>:** As per user1686's request:

```
$ ls /lib/modules
4.20.1-arch1-1-ARCH  5.5.8-arch1-1
$ uname -r
5.5.8-arch1-1
$ cat /proc/cmdline
\\boot\vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=bb81187c-8818-49d5-bec6-bed0c3c82b0c ro initrd=/boot/intel-ucode.img initrd=/boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

I tried Linux 4.20.1 to check if a kernel update caused those issues since I was certain that kernel version used to work, but it had the same issues.

Comment: Can you show the outputs of `ls /lib/modules`, `uname -r`, and `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: @user1686 added

Comment: Aside from the `ro` parameter (which is not standard for the Arch boot process), I'm slightly confused by the `/boot/...` paths in the cmdline. Was this after booting through systemd-boot or through rEFInd? What does the layout of your EFI System Partition look like? (That is, where is it mounted within Linux, and what directories did you create/copy inside it?)

Comment: @user1686 Yes I changed `rw` to `ro` and actually I don't remember why I did it, but I am pretty sure it is unrelated. As for the cmdline, I actually never booted through systemd-boot even once, so if anything it is rEFInd that configured it that way. The EFI partition is `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and it is mounted at `/boot/efi`. Bootloaders are stored in `/boot/efi/EFI/`